# MATCH, INDEX and SMALL Formula for Dates and Times with Multiple Criteria and Multiple Values

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have tried everything but cannot sort this one out. I have multiple sheets in the same book. One with just a list of times, dates and employee numbers. The other sheets are my employees. Each sheet has the employee's name and other details that has to be sorted from my first sheet.

The first sheet looks like this:

[image]

The second sheet has to sort all data from the first sheet according to employee number and date. What I would like to do is get the time from my first sheet based on my date and employee number into my second sheet. Here is the problem . . . the `IF` function does not want to find any value based on a date criteria. I have tried countless ways to work around it. My first sheet does not contain just the date and time but the date and time column both have the date and the time together. i have tried splitting it but no success on my formula.

The only formula I found to work was

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ALL!$C:$C,MATCH('JOHAN HORAK'!C14&$E$2,ALL!$H:$H&ALL!$A:$A,0)),0)
```

this pulls the first value but I need the second, third and fourth value to appear as well but an `INDEX`, `SMALL`, `IF` function only returns and error. My second sheet will have to have the clock in and out times in their appropriate columns.

[image]

Comment: Consider using an array with your  INDEX | MATCH. You can see an example [here](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/). Note that if it's a big file it may take a while to compute. Also, if there's just one time value per column for each employee and day, you could use SUMIFS.

Comment: I have unfortunately used all my views on that specific website. This is already an array formula and works perfect for the first value but I am having difficulty returning the second, third and fourth value from my spreadsheet based on the same criteria as the first Index Match formula. I have tried a small function as follows with no success =INDEX(ALL!$C$2:$C$2500,SMALL(IF(('JOHAN HORAK'!$E$2=ALL!$A$2:$A$2500)&('JOHAN HORAK'!C13=ALL!$H$2:$H$2500),ALL!$C$2:$C$2500,0),ROW(ALL!$C:$C)-ROW(ALL!$A$1)+1),COLUMN(A1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ALL!$C:$C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(ALL!$H:$H)/((ALL!$H:$H='JOHAN HORAK'!C14)*(ALL!$A:$A=E2)),1),0),0)
```